# Why is the function not implemented when I submitted the form?

Tags: reactjs, function, events, submit

The function I pass to the [onsubmit](/questions/tagged/onsubmit) event is not executed when the form is submitted

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Form.module.css';

import Button from './Button';

const Form = function (props) {

  const addUserHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(135);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addUserHandler}>
      <input
        type='text'
        className={styles.input}
        placeholder='Your Age'
        ref={nameInputRef}
      />

      <Button type='submit'>add user</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I expected that the function [adduserhandler](/questions/tagged/adduserhandler) will be executed when I submitted the form.

Comment: Can you post the code of the  `Button` component?

Comment: You should edit the question and add that code so that it is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the `type` correctly from `<Button>` to `<button>`, which means that the `submit` button is rendered as a normal button which does not submit the form. Instead of:

```
<button type={props.type ? 'button' : props.type}>
```

do:

```
<button type={props.type ? props.type : 'button'}>
```

or shorter:

```
<button type={props.type || 'button'}>
```